# How to convert String to Binary in Scheme

Tags: windows, scheme, racket, r5rs

So, I've ran into this problem where I've been trying to code a means to convert a binary number to a string in Scheme (R5RS), but I've been having some....problems. My tutor and I tried to solve it over the course of an hour, but we haven't been able to solve it.

In fact, as of the time I finished the last session, he left behind the following:

```
    (define binary->string (lambda (lst)
                         (define str (make-string 0)) 
                         (letrec ((recurse (lambda (l)
                                             ; turn into not null
                                             (if (null? l)
                                                 (lambda ()
                                                   (set! str (string-append str (number->string (car l))))
                                                   (recurse (cdr l)))
                                                 )
                                             )
                                           )
                                  )
                           (recurse lst)
                          )
                         str)
  )

(binary->string '(0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1))
```

See where it says "turn into not null"? Well, we've had some problems trying to convert the number into not null. I sure hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want this result?

```
> (binary->string '(0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1))
"01010011"
```

I see you've already used [`string-append`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_544) and [`number->string`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_366), so you should also use [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_578) and [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_580):

```
(define (binary->string arg)
  (apply string-append
         (map number->string arg)))

> (binary->string '(0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1))
"01010011"
```

If you also want to convert it into decimal number, use [`string->number`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_544) with *radix* 2:

```
> (string->number "01010011" 2)
83
```